# ID Parsing then using as Selector

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this funny little problem, where I want to parse the IDs of images. Nothing too complicated... but weirdly enough, my code doesn't seem to work properly. It's weirdddd. Could any care to explain this? I feel blind for not being able to see the error myself.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code that fails to work:

```
        //Toggling images using img-index variable.
        img-index = 0;
        img-src[0] = $("#ppsfb").attr("id");
        img-src[1] = $("#gty").attr("id");

        $("#cycle").click(function(){
            //Since img-index is just a counter.
            if (img-index < 2){
            img-index = img-index + 1;
            } else {img-index = 0;}                         

            $(img-src[img-index]).fadeIn(1000);             
        });
```

Comment: not valid variables names, should be `[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*`

Answer (score 1):

`img-src` is not a valid identifier in JavaScript.  That's likely why this is failing.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HzMHv/) and note the `Unexpected token -` error

Answer (score 0):

`img-index` is not a valid variable name in JavaScript, you probably want to use `img_index` or `imgIndex`. Also, calling `attr('id')` on something that comes from an ID selector is pointless, `$("#ppsfb").attr("id")` is `'ppsfb'` or nothing. You're probably better off storing whole jQuery objects in `img_src` too, your `$(img-src[img-index])` wouldn't do what you wanted it to do even after fixing the naming problem. Furthermore, you probably want to hide or fadeout the current image before showing the new one.

```
img_index = 0;
img_src[0] = $('#ppsfb');
img_src[1] = $('#gty');

$("#cycle").click(function(){
    img_src[img_index].hide() // Or .fadeOut or ...
    if(img_index < 2)
        img_index = img_index + 1;
    else
        img_index = 0;
    img_src[img_index].fadeIn(1000);             
});
```

Presumably you have the positioning, stacking, etc. already sorted out.

Comment: lol, I feel so stupid. It's not that I'm not experienced. I just confused valid name types in HTML and Javascript. I always make bad assumptions with Javascript (since it's so versatile).